# Is there a way to generate Firestore classes in Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am planning a messaging app using Firebase with a python backend, and have a bunch of classes I want to implement, corresponding to documents.

Eg.

Users/{user_id}

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, id, first_name, last_name):
       #....
     
    def to_dict(self):
       #....

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(source):
       return User(source['id'], source['first_name'], source['last_name'])
```

And sub-collections like user messages : Users/{user_id}/Messages/{message_id}

```
class Message:
    def __init__(self, id, text_string):
       #....
     
    def to_dict(self):
       #....

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(source):
       return Message(source['id'], source['text_string'])
```

...and so on.

Is there some standard way I can automatically generate this code for all classes I have, and perhaps maintain it in accordance a schema document?

I looked at https://pypi.org/project/firestore-model/, which seemed useful, but couldn't get it to work for sub-collections.

Comment: An online way to do this could be https://app.quicktype.io/. I have tried generating the above scenario using the online tool and it seems to work. And also have a look here as well https://pypi.org/project/fireclass/